# Анимация из массива (JS animation)

Tags: javascript, svg, анимация

https://dribbble.com/SSAdesign11 есть вот такая анимашка, клиент хочет подобную, но имажек там около 150, создавать подобное путём css анимации, конечно же возможно, но довольно трудозатратно. Подскажите плиз, возможно кто-то сталкивался с подобной реализацией на js? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: какая именно анимация нужная?

Comment: появление? на самом деле есть хорошее правило, что можно сделать на css лучше сделать на css. В данном случае, js будет расставлять изображения ( хотя если сами сиволы не меняются, то и css может все сделать )

Comment: я всегда придерживаюсь этого правила, но в данном случае боюсь, что сойду с ума. http://prntscr.com/p0tcld - вот такая и это только часть. с помощью сss я это сделаю, но, как мне кажется, есть более интересные решения на js. естественно я не прошу готовое решение, но если подскажите ресурс, где можно посмотреть возможные варианты решения - буду благодарен.

Comment: @IgorKushtym проблема с позиционированием? или с созданием css из js?

Comment: @Stranger in the Q, даже не знаю как объяснить. наверное так, как создать массив объектов и спозиционировать данные объекты определённым образом. или даже так - как создать подобное https://dribbble.com/SSAdesign11, но не css как здесь, а js.

Comment: все что нужно знать координаты, на которых должны быть картинки. Самый простой способ, это забить эти координаты руками. А потом в цикле пройтись)

Comment: Не вижу проблем с анимацией на css.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Похоже? Откройте на весь экран... или кликните в любом месте страницы...

Картиночки выстраиваются вдоль svg path

```js
function reload() {
  images.classList.remove('fall')
  images.innerHTML = [...document.querySelectorAll('path')].map(handle).join('');
  setTimeout(() => images.classList.add('fall'));
}

reload();

addEventListener('click', reload);
addEventListener('resize', reload);

function handle(path) {
  let w = innerWidth/40, h = innerHeight/30;
  let len = path.getTotalLength();
  let result = ''
  for (var t = 0; t < len; t += 5) {
    let p = path.getPointAtLength(t).matrixTransform(path.getScreenCTM());
    result += `<img class="img" style='transition: ${1 + Math.random()}s;  
        left:${p.x-w/2}px; top: ${p.y-h/2}px;width:${w}px; height:${h}px' 
        src='https://picsum.photos/id/${Math.floor(Math.random()*50)}/50/50'>`;
  }
  return result;
}
```

```css
.fall img {
  transform: translateZ(0px);
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  perspective: 400px;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateZ(1000px);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.03,.8,.41,1.04);
}

img:hover {
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewbox=0,0,100,100 height=100vh width=100vw>
  <path fill=none id=p1 d="m25,70v-40l-20,30h25"></path>
  <path fill=none id=p2 d="m38,40a12,12,0,0,1,24,0v20a12,12,0,0,1,-24,0v-20"></path>
  <path fill=none id=p3 d="m90,70v-40l-20,30h25"></path>
</svg>
<div id=images></div>
```

Comment: Мощно)) Мне нравится!!!

Comment: @Mully тут есть еще с чем пошаманить но в целом идея я думаю ясна

Comment: @StrangerintheQ идеально. спасибо большое. да идея более чем ясна, а подшаманить теперь не составит труда

Comment: @IgorKushtym я путь тут сам составлял, однако можно воспользоваться векторным редактором для этого

Comment: @StrangerintheQ да, это я уже понял, как раз сижу ковыряюсь. ещё раз большое спасибо.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ извините - исправился =)

Comment: @Stranger in the Q действительно интересно

Comment: Это прекрасно).